# My date function is not working on firefox but works on chrome

Tags: reactjs, date

I am using Date() function in my react code. Date function is running on chrome fine but working on firefox.

I have tried to convert the date in miliseconds.

```
var getnewdate = "Wed Jun 26 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
alert(getnewdate);
var getCurrentDayInMilli = new Date(getnewdate).getTime() / 100000;
alert(getCurrentDayInMilli);
```

alert(getnewdate); prints "Tue Jun 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" on chrome which is correct but on firefox it prints "Invalid Date" which is not correct.

I want my alert function should work fine in firefox as well like chrome.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): *"[...] parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor [...] is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."*

Comment: After you update your post, this is working fine in firefox also.

Comment: Yes but my updated post creating problem in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Use date in this format `yyyy/MM/dd(you can have any format of date) HH:mm:ss(this is required)`, this will work in all the browsers,

```
var getselectdate = "Jun-27-2019 12:00:00";
```